# Twitter Bootstrap: Remember accordion expand / collapse state

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, accordion, state

I've found quite a few solutions whereby the expand/collapse state of a jQuery Accordion can be persisted across page post backs or reloads, but have not found anything for Twitter Bootstrap Accordions yet.

Has someone came across a solution that works well?

Comment: Which server side technology are you using?

Comment: I'm using .NET, but I was looking for a client-side solution using either cookies or local storage.

Comment: So you want the state to be saved between sessions? Because if not I use to keep the state with a JSON object in a hidden field